# Get a unique list of values in a column from one sheet to another

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with three worksheets

- Master
- Migration
- Dashboard

How would I create a unique list of all the values in the Master sheet column T and put it in the Dashboard sheet (starting from A6 onwards)?

Comment: read article [filter for unique values or remove duplicate values](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't work - says I can only copy it to the active sheet

Comment: copy on active sheet, and then copy unique values from active sheet to Dashboard sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, col As Collection
    Dim j As Long
    Set w1 = Sheets("Master")
    Set w2 = Sheets("Dashboard")
    N = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
    Set col = New Collection
    For i = 1 To N
        v = w1.Cells(i, "T").Value
        cv = CStr(v)
        On Error Resume Next
        col.Add v, cv
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            w2.Range("A6").Offset(j, 0).Value = w1.Cells(i, "T")
            j = j + 1
        Else
            Err.Number = 0
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```